# Paperclip: Saving Base64 encoded file, saved without extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to save Base64 encoded string using paperclip on rails, but the resulting file has no extension

The encoded string is as follows:

```
{"model"=>{"photo"=>"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j..}
```

The paperclip configurations

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :styles => { medium: "380x380>", small: "200x200>", thumb: "100x100>" },
                :path => ":rails_root/model/:style/:id.:extension",
                :url => "/object_image/model/:style/:id.:extension",                    
                  :default_url => "/images/default-avatar.png"

validates_attachment_content_type :photo,
                                  :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg",
                                                    "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

The resulting file is : `1.`

Any help is appeciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tries to set back the extension using the image's content type

```
tempfile = self.image.queued_for_write[:original]
unless tempfile.nil?
  extension = File.extname(tempfile.original_filename)
  if !extension || extension == ''
    mime = tempfile.content_type
    ext = Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[mime]
    self.image.instance_write :file_name, "#{tempfile.original_filename}#{ext}"
  end
end
```

special thanks to stackoverflow.